# laravel package spatie/browsershot is not taking non-latin characters like Arabic, Chinese

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the browsershot of the html template i have created.
I have installed.
spatie/browsershot => 3.57.2
laravel => 8

I have written below code, which is working fine locally But not on aws server.

```
   $poster_img_generation = new Browsershot($url, true);
   $poster_img_generation
    ->setScreenshotType('jpeg',100)
   ->windowSize($imageWidth,$imageHeight)
   ->fullPage()
   ->landscape(true)
   ->setDelay(1000)
   ->save($imgFilePath);
```

The code is working fine with English languages on server but it is not working with Chinese, Korean etc languages it is printing empty boxes.